# remove lines that contain a specific text in a file

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a file with a list of emails in it and each line has an email in it. I want to remove lines that contain the string `example.com` or `test.com`.

I tried this:

```
sed -i 's/example\.com//ig' file.txt
```

But it will remove only the string `example.com`, how can I remove the entire line?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed '/example\.com/d;/test\.com/d' -i file.txt
```

will remove the lines with `example.com` and `test.com`.

From `man sed`:

```
d      Delete pattern space.  Start next cycle.
```

Comment: This will also delete line contain `example` (or `test`) follow by any character then `com`. Example `echo 'exampleAcom' | sed '/example.com/d'`

Comment: Gah, silly me absent-mindedly not escaping the dot. Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 6):

POSIXly, you can use `grep`:

```
grep -Eiv '(example|test)\.com' <in >out
```

Comment: Be careful not to use the same file for input and output, or it will be truncated before `grep` can read it.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex only matches `example.com` and `sed` replaces only `example.com`s with empty string. Your regex should match any line containing example.com or test.com

```
sed -i 's@.*\(test\|example\)\.com.*@@i' file.txt
```

Comment: Your answer does not delete matching lines; it only makes them blank. – It also does not handle case insensitive text (as per the OP's example). –. The `g`  is redundant/meaningless, because `sed`‍'s regex is greedy and therefore the leading and trailing `.*`  will cause the 1st occurrence of a text match to match the entire line. ‍

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I haven't paid attention to case sensivity. `g` is my habit, you are right, it is not neccesary. Also I thought, blanking line was what OP wanted. Now everything is clear. Thanks