# Deleting portion of a text file and following lines using sed

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I need to edit a file like the following:

```
auto wlx00
allow-hotplug wlx00
iface wlx000 inet dhcp
iface wlx000 inet6 auto
  post-up sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.wlx000.accept_ra=2
auto wlx000
```

the goal is to delete the lines starting with 'iface...inet6' and also delete the next few that start with space (can be none or more than one):

```
iface wlx000 inet6 auto
  post-up sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.wlx000.accept_ra=2
```

and keep the rest intact for the following result:

```
auto wlx00
allow-hotplug wlx00
iface wlx000 inet dhcp
auto wlx000
```

I tried with sed using as follows:

```
sed -i.old -r -e "/iface\s*\w*\s*inet6.*/,\${d;/^\s.*/d;}" /etc/configfile
```

but it removes everything starting at the right place but erasing to the end. I just want to remove lines staring with space after the select iface text.

Comment: @fcm please let us know  if the solutions below are ok. if not we can tweak it for you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove lines that contain a specific text in a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224697/remove-lines-that-contain-a-specific-text-in-a-file)

Comment: @TNT not the same question. This is NOT to delete a single line, is delete a line plus following lines staring with space.

Comment: Theoretically a duplicate, but not in practice -- I think it'd be good to provide a separate answer here that demonstrates how to match from a given pattern through subsequent lines that have leading whitespace.

Comment: @rudic provided an excellent and elaborated answer that is far from being a simple search and delete, nothing on the suggested dup nears that.

Comment: It's not even theoretically a duplicate, M. Schalller.  This is Debian's `/etc/network/interfaces`.  That has a specific (and not very well documented) syntax comprising multiple-line _stanzas_.  I parse it with `awk` myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this adaption of your `sed` one liner:

```
sed  '/iface\s*\w*\s*inet6.*/,/^[^ ]/ {/^[^ i]/!d}' file
```

It matches the range from your first pattern to the first line NOT starting with a space char, and deletes the lines starting with space or an "i" (for the leading `iface`). Need to rethink should the `i` be required after the block.

Looks like this works:

```
sed -n '/iface\s*\w*\s*inet6.*/ {:L; n; /^[ ]/bL;}; p' file
```

Pls try and report back.

Answer (score 6):

A script for standard `sed` that uses an explicit loop to delete the lines:

```
/^iface .* inet6/ {
    :again
    N
    s/.*\n//
    /^[[:blank:]]/b again
}
```

The script finds the `inet6` lines and then appends the next line to that line internally in the pattern space (with an embedded newline character in-between). It then deletes the pattern space up to and including the first newline character (this deletes the original `inet6` line).  It continues doing this until the pattern space does not start with a blank character (space or tab).

Testing:

```
$ cat file
auto wlx00
allow-hotplug wlx00
iface wlx000 inet dhcp
iface wlx000 inet6 auto
  post-up sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.wlx000.accept_ra=2
auto wlx000
```

```
$ sed -f script.sed <file
auto wlx00
allow-hotplug wlx00
iface wlx000 inet dhcp
auto wlx000
```

Testing on artificial data:

```
$ cat file
something1
something2
iface have a inet6 here
   delete me
   me too
   same here
something3
something4
iface more something inet6
   be gone
   skip this
something5
```

```
$ sed -f script.sed <file
something1
something2
something3
something4
something5
```

The script as a "one-liner":

```
sed -e '/^iface .* inet6/ {' -e ':a' -e 'N;s/.*\n//;/^[[:blank:]]/ba' -e '}'
```

Answer (score 3):

You've already got good answers for `sed` tool, but let me propose other, I believe much simpler, approach using `pcregrep`:

```
pcregrep -Mv '^iface.*inet6(.|\n )*' file
```

The regex should be self-explanatory - we search for pattern starting from the line `^iface.*inet6` and then group of any character OR new line followed by single space repeated zero or more times. Then we just need to instruct `pcregrep` to allow multi-linear matching with `-M` option and reverse the whole thing by `-v` (matched part will be removed).

Comment: I usually prefer to use `pcregrep`, far more intuitive.